# Numba and Cython not providing performance improvements over regular Python

Tags: python, numpy, cython, numba

I have some Python code that I have been trying to speed up with Numba and then Cython. Numba is about 2x slower (one issue is it doesn't support np.var with an axis argument but that can't be the only cause), and Cython runs in more or less exactly the same time.
Here is the Numba version:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from itertools import product
from numba import jit, objmode, prange
import time
import cProfile
import pstats

@jit(nopython=True)
def squeeze(X, n, d):
    sum_values = [[0.0] * n for _ in range(n)]
    for i in range(n):
        for j in range(n):
            sum_values[i][j] = np.sum(X[i, :, j])
    return sum_values

@jit(nopython=True)
def calculate_variance2(X):
    n, d, _ = X.shape
    a = np.sum(X, axis=1)
    b = np.zeros(n)
    for i in range(n):
        b[i] = np.var(a[:, i])
    return np.sum(b)


@jit(nopython=True)
def get_X_beta2(n, d, tau):
    X = np.zeros((n, d + 1, n))
    for k in prange(n):
        for j in range(d):
            X[0, j, k] = V[k, j]

    for k in prange(n):
        X[k, d, k] = -tau[k, 0]

    beta = np.zeros((d, n))
    for k in prange(n):
        for j in prange(d):
            beta[j, k] = V[k, j] / V[0, j]

    return X, beta

@jit(nopython=True)
def update_params(X, beta, alloc_mt, uu):
    j1 = np.random.randint(0, d)
    temp = np.sum(X, axis=1) - X[:, j1, :]

    I = np.argmin(np.dot(temp, beta[j1, :]))
    X[:, j1, :] = 0
    X[I, j1, :] = V[:, j1]
    alloc_mt[uu, :, j1] = 0

    return X, alloc_mt

@jit(nopython=True)
def get_mct_E(V, n, d):
    TAR = 51
    upper = 2000
    target = np.linspace(0, upper, TAR)

    envy_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    util_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    alloc_mt = np.zeros((TAR, n, d))

    for uu in prange(TAR):
        num_optims = 0

        tau = np.repeat(target[uu], n).reshape(n, 1)

        X, beta = get_X_beta2(n, d, tau)

        alloc_mt[uu, 0, :] = np.ones((1, d))

        counter = 0
        variance = calculate_variance2(X) / n
 
        while counter < d:
         
            X, alloc_mt = update_params(X, beta, alloc_mt, uu)
          
            variance_temp = calculate_variance2(X) / n
          

            if variance_temp < variance:
                variance = variance_temp
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1
     
        X = X[:, :d, :]

        E = np.array(squeeze(X,n,d))
        envy_mc[uu] = calc_envy(E, n)
        util_mc[uu] = calc_util(E, d)
 
    print(sum(envy_mc))
    return envy_mc, util_mc, alloc_mt

def min_cov_target2(V, n, d):
    envy_mc, util_mc, alloc_mt = get_mct_E(V, n, d)

    envy_mct = np.min(envy_mc)
    min_envy_index = np.where(envy_mc == envy_mct)[0]
    m = np.argmax(util_mc[min_envy_index])
    tt = min_envy_index[m]

    envy_mct = envy_mc[tt]
    alloc_mct = np.reshape(alloc_mt[tt, :, :], (n, d))
    X = np.zeros((n, d, n))
    for k in range(n):
        X[:, :, k] = alloc_mct * np.tile(V[k, :], (n, 1))
    E_mct = np.squeeze(np.sum(X, axis=1))

    print(alloc_mct)

@jit(nopython=True)
def kroneckerproduct(A, B, row_a, col_a, row_b, col_b):
    C = np.zeros((row_a * row_b, col_a * col_b))
    for i in range(row_a):
        for j in range(col_a):
            for k in range(row_b):
                for l in range(col_b):
                    C[i * row_b + k, j * col_b + l] = A[i] * B[k, l]
    return numpy_to_list_of_lists(C)

@jit(nopython=True)
def numpy_to_list_of_lists(arr):
    if arr.ndim == 1:  # Handle 1D array separately
        return [[item for item in arr]]
    else:
        list_of_lists = []
        for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
            row_list = [arr[i, j] for j in range(arr.shape[1])]
            list_of_lists.append(row_list)
        return list_of_lists

@jit(nopython=True)
def find_max_value(arr):
    max_value = arr[0, 0]
    for i in range(arr.shape[0]):
        for j in range(arr.shape[1]):
            if arr[i, j] > max_value:
                max_value = arr[i, j]
    return max_value

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_envy(E, n):
    A = np.diag(E)
    B = np.transpose(np.ones((1, n)))
    return find_max_value(E - \
    np.transpose(np.array(kroneckerproduct(A,B, A.shape[0],1, B.shape[0], B.shape[1])).reshape(n,n)))

@jit(nopython=True)
def calc_util(E, d):
    A = np.diag(E)
    return sum(A)

# Press the green button in the gutter to run the script.
if __name__ == '__main__':

    V = np.array([
        [121, 94, 141, 142, 63, 97, 101, 97, 41, 103],
        [193, 21, 205, 103, 195, 8, 161, 36, 10, 68],
        [23, 51, 29, 145, 144, 154, 135, 128, 18, 173],
        [159, 95, 169, 25, 167, 162, 68, 6, 143, 6]
    ])
    n = 4
    d = 10
    
    min_cov_target2(V, n, d)
```

and the Cython version

```
import numpy as np
cimport numpy as cnp
cimport cython

cnp.import_array()
DTYPE = np.int64
ctypedef cnp.int64_t DTYPE_t

@cython.boundscheck(False) # turn off bounds-checking for entire function
@cython.wraparound(False)  # turn off negative index wrapping for entire function
def mct(cnp.ndarray[int, ndim=2] V, int n, int d):
    cdef cnp.int64_t TAR = 51
    cdef cnp.int64_t upper = 2000
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=1] target = np.linspace(0, upper, TAR)
    cdef cnp.int64_t envy_mct = 0
    cdef cnp.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim=1] min_envy_index
    cdef cnp.int64_t envy_o_index = 0
    cdef cnp.int64_t I = 0
    cdef cnp.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 3] alloc_mt = np.zeros((TAR, n, d), dtype=np.int64)
    cdef cnp.ndarray[DTYPE_t, ndim = 2] alloc_mt_out = np.zeros((n, d), dtype=np.int64)
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=3] X = np.zeros((n, d, n))
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=2] E = np.zeros((n, n))
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=1] envy_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=1] util_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=2] tau
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=2] beta = np.zeros((n, d))
    cdef int uu, k, j, counter, j1
    cdef cnp.ndarray[double, ndim=2] temp
    cdef double variance, temp_variance
    
    for uu in range(TAR):
        tau = np.tile(target[uu], (n, 1))

        X = np.zeros((n, d+1, n))
        for k in range(n):
            for j in range(d):
                X[0, j, k] = V[k, j]

        for k in range(n):
            X[k, d, k] = -tau[k]

        beta = np.zeros((n, d))
        for k in range(n):
            for j in range(d):
                beta[k, j] = V[k, j] / V[0, j]

        alloc_mt[uu, 0, :] = np.ones((1,d), dtype=int)

        counter = 0
        variance = np.sum(np.var(np.sum(X, axis=1), axis=0)) / n

        while counter < d:
            j1 = np.random.randint(0, d)
            temp = np.sum(X, axis=1) - X[:, j1, :]
            I = np.argmin(temp.dot(beta[:, j1]))

            X[:, j1, :] = 0
            X[I, j1, :] = V[:, j1]
            alloc_mt[uu, :, j1] = 0
            alloc_mt[uu, I, j1] = 1
            temp_variance = np.sum(np.var(np.sum(X, axis=1), axis=0)) / n
            if temp_variance < variance:
                variance = temp_variance
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1
        
        X = X[:, :d, :]

        E = np.squeeze(np.sum(X, axis=1))
        util_mc[uu] = sum((np.diag(E)));
        envy_mc[uu] = np.max(np.max(E - np.kron(np.diag(E), np.transpose(np.ones((1, n))))))

    envy_mct = np.min(envy_mc)
    min_envy_index = np.where(envy_mc == envy_mct)[0]
    m = np.argmax(util_mc[min_envy_index])
    tt = min_envy_index[m]

    envy_mct = envy_mc[tt]
    alloc_mct_out = np.reshape(alloc_mt[tt, :, :], (n, d))
    return alloc_mct_out
```

and the original Python

```
def min_cov_target(V, n, d):
    TAR = 51
    upper = 2000
    target = np.linspace(0, upper, TAR)

    envy_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    util_mc = np.zeros(TAR)
    alloc_mt = np.zeros((TAR, n, d))

    for uu in range(TAR):
        num_optims = 0
        tau = np.tile(target[uu], (n, 1))

        X = np.zeros((n, d+1, n))
        for k in range(n):
            for j in range(d):
                X[0, j, k] = V[k, j]

        for k in range(n):
            X[k, d, k] = -tau[k]

        beta = np.zeros((n, d))
        for k in range(n):
            for j in range(d):
                beta[k, j] = V[k, j] / V[0, j]

        alloc_mt[uu, 0, :] = np.ones((1,d))

        counter = 0
        variance = np.sum(np.var(np.sum(X, axis=1), axis=0)) / n

        while counter < d:
            num_optims += 1
            j1 = np.random.randint(0, d)
            temp = np.sum(X, axis=1) - X[:, j1, :]
            # M = np.min(temp.dot(beta[:, j1]))
            I = np.argmin(temp.dot(beta[:, j1]))

            X[:, j1, :] = 0
            X[I, j1, :] = V[:, j1]
            alloc_mt[uu, :, j1] = 0
            alloc_mt[uu, I, j1] = 1

            temp_variance = np.sum(np.var(np.sum(X, axis=1), axis=0)) / n
            if temp_variance < variance:
                variance = temp_variance
                counter = 0
            else:
                counter += 1
        #print(num_optims)
        X = X[:, :d, :]

        E = np.squeeze(np.sum(X, axis=1))
        util_mc[uu] = sum((np.diag(E)));
        envy_mc[uu] = np.max(np.max(E - np.kron(np.diag(E), np.transpose(np.ones((1, n))))))

    envy_mct = np.min(envy_mc)
    min_envy_index = np.where(envy_mc == envy_mct)[0]
    m = np.argmax(util_mc[min_envy_index])
    tt = min_envy_index[m]

    envy_mct = envy_mc[tt]
    alloc_mct = np.reshape(alloc_mt[tt, :, :], (n, d))

    print(alloc_mct)
```

Is it surprising that there is no performance improvement moving to Numba or Cython, and is there anything I can do to improve performance?

Comment: Is the 'original python' code complete? currently ```E_mct```, ```envy_mcov``` and ```E_mcov``` aren't accessed

Comment: Sorry about the confusion. Yes it is complete, that's some legacy code that isn't used. I will remove it

Comment: This is unfortunately an antipattern I see a lot with Numba use. Far before attempting a Numba JIT, you should be properly vectorizing away your loops, and that hasn't been done here.

Answer (score 0):

Numba is not a magic wand. It will not paper over misuse of Numpy APIs, and you've found as much in your performance experiments.

I provide three examples where functions should be rewritten to use vectorized alternatives:

`squeeze` should just be

```py
def squeeze(X: np.ndarray, n: int) -> np.ndarray:
    return X[:n, :, :n].sum(axis=1)
```

`find_max_value` should just be

```py
def find_max_value(arr: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return arr.max()
```

`calc_util` should just be

```py
def calc_util(E: np.ndarray) -> float:
    return E.trace()
```

You need to similarly rewrite all of your other code to properly use vectorization and the features of Numpy that remove your need for looping.

Comment: But the loops are not the performance bottleneck? I agree there are some unnecessary loops, especially in the JIT code (mainly because it didn't support things like np.,var(axis)) but the 2 methods that take all the time are update_params and calculate_variance2 (first one has no loop, second one only has a loop because I can't use np.var(axis) )

Comment: [var has an axis parameter](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.var.html)

Comment: Yes but that isn't supported in Numba

Comment: https://numba.readthedocs.io/en/stable/reference/numpysupported.html